# GWT JSONObject to overlay types (or using JSONObject in shared)

Tags: java, json, gwt, gxt, jsni

I fill an JSONArray (org.JSON) on my GWT server side, then want to use the object on the client side. When I use a JSONObject (or Array) in my shared package, I get the exception that there was no source found (while it works on the server). Thus, I presume it cannot be used client side, or shared (could not confirm that despite googling).

Since shared would not use JSONObject, I presumed JSNI would work in shared. I have read into GWT overlay types on google developer and here on stackoverflow, and have made one in my shared package. However, since it is JSNI, it is not usable on the server. Therefore, I try to pass the JSONObject.toString() to my shared class, then use it as parameter for calling the following JSNI method:

```
public native UserOverlay getUser(String jsonObj) /*-{
    return jsonObj;
}-*/;
```

the call:

```
UserOverlay user = getUser(jsonobj);
```

However, this gives an UnsatisfiedLinkError at the location of the call, which as far as I know means that the JSNI method was not found, meaning that the shared package does NOT work with JSNI.

**Conclusion**

I need a method to use my JSON data on both Client, shared and server. If that method differs, then I need a way to convert one method to the other. I have seen threads that handle converting from overlay types to JSONObject, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to [Crockford's JSON implementation for Java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java), the reason it can't be used on the client code is that it needs to be [emulated](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation) first. For your purposes, you'd wanna use a different approach;

Have the server returning a JSON text response (over HTTP, naturally), request it via XHR on the client, and than use the response in its raw form — as [JSON is a subset of JavaScript's literal object notation](http://www.json.org/js.html), it can be used transparently within JavaScript code.

To implement this approach in GWT, create a servlet that returns the JSON as text (outputs it to the response's writer). This servlet can than be called from the client using [`RequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) (which wraps XHR), and overlay types can be used to convert each JSON response to Java managed objects according to its contract.

The Google Developer documentation offers a tutorial on [Retrieving JSON](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON), discussing just that. I'll encompass the highlights and some snippets, just for the sake of completeness:

1. **Create a servlet serving JSON**

   *Don't forget to configure the webapp's deployment descriptor (`web.xml`) accordingly.*

   ```java
   public class JsonDataServlet extends HttpServlet {

       @Override
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

           PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
           out.println('{');
           // fill with JSON construct
           out.println('}');
           out.flush();
       }

   }
   ```
2. **Construct the overlay types according to the response's interface**
3. **Create client side utilities to convert the JSON response to a concrete `JavaScriptObject`**

   *The tutorial suggests the use of `eval()` inside a JSNI method, but I prefer to utilize [`JSONParser.parseStrict()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html#parseStrict%28java.lang.String%29) as it will first try and call JavaScript's `JSON.parse()` on supporting browsers.*

   ```java
   public static UserOverlay asUserOverlay(String json) {
       JSONValue jsonVal = JSONParser.parseStrict(json);
       JSONObject jsonObj = jsonVal.isObject();
       UserOverlay userOverlay = (UserOverlay) jsonObj.getJavaScriptObject();
   }
   ```

   ***Note:** If you're gonna use the `eval()` implementation anyway, the `json` argument needs to be wrapped in parentheses, i.e. `eval('(' + json + ')')`.*
4. **Call the servlet**

   ```java
   RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "path/to/servlet");
   rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

       public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
           // do something
       }

       public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
           if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
               UserOverlay userOverlay = asUserOverlay(response.getText());
               // continue handling
           }
       }
   });
   rb.send();
   ```

#### References on the Google Web Toolkit documentation

- [Retrieving JSON Data](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON)
- [Working With JSON](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON)
- [Communicate With A Server](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests)

Comment: +much for a very complete answer and some useful links. I've pretty much used this method, as mentioned in my own answer. I save the JSON result as a String in the bean that I need to send in result from my AsyncCallback anyway. Thanks for a high quality answer and some good reads!

Answer (score 0):

I am now saving the JSON as a String in the shared package.

I use org.JSON to do what I need to do with what I fetch on the server, and overlay types in the client.

I use `aJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();` to get the JSON String when sending it to the client, and store it in my serializable as that String, then call my native overlay type function on the client. Works like a charm, but I am unsure if it's the best way. It seems the only.